# Timeout Exceptions and Stale elements despite element existing (wait until not working)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Timeout Exceptions and Stale elements despite element existing.

```
//a1[contains(@class, 'tb1_header-bar tb113')]
```

See here:

Comment: Element could be in iframe...in that case you have to switch to that frame..or it could be down in page..so you need to scroll through page first.

Comment: I like that idea.  Sadly though, this did not solve